# SQL Server - Unsupported Keystore Provider MSSQL_JAVA_KEYSTORE

Tags: sql-server, always-encrypted

I am working on a project where we plan to encrypt our SQL Server 2016 database using SQL Server Always Encrypted. The client apps will access data via a compatible jdbc driver.

Microsoft docs say that I can use `MSSQL_JAVA_KEYSTORE` as the Keystore provider.

- Step 1: I created a KeyPair using keytool command and I have a jks file.
- Step 2: I created a Column Master Key in SQL Server using SSMS as follows

  ```
  CREATE COLUMN MASTER KEY CMK_2
  WITH
      (KEY_STORE_PROVIDER_NAME = N'MSSQL_JAVA_KEYSTORE',
       KEY_PATH = N'tp-7b679880-706e-47af-bcbe-e1cc3cc78690');
  ```

  where `KEY_PATH` is the alias of the key in my `keystore.jks` file.
- Step 3: Now I am trying to create a Column Encryption key using SSMS wizard and it throws the following Error

  > Unsupported Keystore Provider type: MSSQL_JAVA_KEYSTORE.

A bit baffled by the error - as per Microsoft docs, `MSSQL_JAVA_KEYSTORE` is one of the built in column master keystore providers.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#creating-a-column-encryption-key-for-the-java-key-store

Comment: I think the take-home point from lptr's link is: _NOTE: The built-in SQL Server management Studio functionality cannot create column master key definitions for the Java Key Store. T-SQL commands must be used programmatically._ In other words you need to do it from a Java app whose JDBC connection string has the correct columnEncryptionSetting , keyStoreAuthentication, keyStoreLocation and keyStoreSecret properties.

Comment: thank you guys for pointing that out. I overlooked that part while reading.   Has anyone tried this or know anyone who has done this?

Comment: Any new insights about the hybrid Microsoft Cert Store - Java Key Store usecase?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately is not possible to create the ECK directly using SSMS. I hope in the future microsoft could handle this. I've used AE with Java app using JBoss EAP 7.x using this steps:

- Keytool to creating the keys.
- Following the guide of Microsoft SQL guide to create a java class and after an EMK and ECK with it.
- Creating my db table objects making reference of this ECK.
- In the jdbc, inform the keystore, its password and connection properties to the sql server.

Important:

- MSSQL will not be able to handle the crypt data register inside the DB. It cannot read the keystore.
- You'll need to create another class or java app with the same keystore access to be able to handle the data (CRUD) actions and troubleshooting the register inside your database.
- If this AE keystore be exposed all your data may be at risk, Keep then safe.

Tip: With DBeaver and Squirrel I could make some select commands using the keystore, and make changes and table structure normally. But insert, update not, only using java class.